# Скролбар в PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Вопрос, как добавить скроллбар, что бы при уменьшении окна он появлялся?

```
class Window(QScrollArea):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOn)
        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)

        # self.ex = TankWindow(self)
        # self.setWidget(self.ex)

class TankWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.players_tech = QComboBox(self)
        self.players_tech.setGeometry(9, 5, 180, 25)
        self.players_tech.addItem('')
        self.filling_player_tech()
        self.players_tech.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        # Объявление label'ов

        w = Window()
        w.show()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 1380, 600)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tech')
        self.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы [QScrollArea](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) начала отображать содержимое виджета с ползунками, нужно помещать внутрь нее виджет через метод [setWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html#setWidget):

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


app = QApplication([])

w = QLabel('Hello World!\n' * 10)
w.setFont(QFont('Arial', 40))

scroll_area = QScrollArea()
scroll_area.setWidget(w)

scroll_area.show()

app.exec()
```

Скриншот:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я попытался сделать так как вы написали:



<code>
self.label_engine = QLabel(self)
        self.label_engine.move(10, 575)
        self.label_engine.setText('Engine characteristics: ')
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.label_engine)
        # for i in scroll_area_list:
        #     scroll_area.setWidget(i)
        scroll_area.show()</code>
Но при запуске выдаёт ошибку: self.label_engine = QLabel(self)
        self.label_engine.move(10, 575)
        self.label_engine.setText('Engine characteristics: ')
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.label_engine)

Comment: @СтепанМолостов По тому коду, что вы приложили проблем нет. Разве что `move` вызывать бессмысленно, а что за ошибка?

Comment: @СтепанМолостов, попробуйте сделать минимальный воспроизводимый пример проблемы, чтобы любой мог запустить и увидеть ту ошибку, и приложите пример (лучше к вопросу, но если не хотите, то ссылкой в комментарий сюда)

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738394/%D0%9D%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB-%D0%B1%D0%B0%D1%80