# Не отображается скролл бар

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

При добавление скролл бара он не отображается, можете помочь, что не так?

```
class TankWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        scroll_area = QScrollArea()

        self.players_tech = QComboBox(self)
        self.players_tech.setGeometry(9, 5, 180, 25)
        self.players_tech.addItem('')
        self.filling_player_tech()
        self.players_tech.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.label_max_weight = QLabel(self)
        self.label_max_weight.move(10, 35)
        self.label_max_weight.setText('Real weight(kg): ')
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.label_max_weight)

        self.label_engine = QLabel(self)
        self.label_engine.move(10, 575)
        self.label_engine.setText('Engine characteristics: ')
        scroll_area.setWidget(self.label_engine)

        scroll_area.show()

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 450)
        self.setWindowTitle('Tech')
        self.show()
```

Comment: А все виджеты нужно на scroll_area разместить или только self.label_engine? Кроме того, scroll_area нужно тоже расположить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного поигрался с кодом из вопроса и привожу пример создания scrollarea:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *


class TankWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle('Tech')

        scroll_area = QScrollArea()

        self.players_tech = QComboBox()
        self.players_tech.addItem('1')
        self.players_tech.addItem('2')
        self.players_tech.addItem('3')
        self.players_tech.addItem('4')
        # self.filling_player_tech()
        # self.players_tech.activated[str].connect(self.onActivated)

        self.label_max_weight = QLabel()
        self.label_max_weight.setText('Real weight(kg): ')

        self.label_engine = QLabel()
        self.label_engine.setText('Engine characteristics: ')

        self.line_edit_max_weight = QLineEdit()
        self.line_edit_engine = QLineEdit()

        # Чтобы на scroll_area разместить несколько виджетов, их предварительно поместить на виджет
        scroll_area_widget_layout = QGridLayout()
        scroll_area_widget_layout.addWidget(self.players_tech, 0, 0)

        scroll_area_widget_layout.addWidget(self.label_max_weight, 1, 0)
        scroll_area_widget_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_max_weight, 1, 1)

        scroll_area_widget_layout.addWidget(self.label_engine, 2, 0)
        scroll_area_widget_layout.addWidget(self.line_edit_engine, 2, 1)

        scroll_area_widget = QWidget()
        scroll_area_widget.setLayout(scroll_area_widget_layout)

        scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_area_widget)

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(scroll_area)

        self.setLayout(layout)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 450)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication([])

    w = TankWindow()
    w.show()

    app.exec()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]